# Objective-C: Adding to variable before assignment

Tags: objective-c

I have the following code:

```
 NSInteger variableScene = 10;
 NSInteger numberOfRowsXX = //an Integer value; <-- I would like replace XX with the value of 'variableScene'
```

So it'll look like this:

```
NSInteger numberOfRows10 == //an Integer value;
```

How can I replace XX with the value of variableScene?

****Update****

Why I'm trying accomplish this?

It's a bit complicated.  I'm using Core Data with remote Database.  In a nutshell: I have 10 `Scenes` that'll be presented based on the User selection order.  For each `Scene` I need to assign the numberOfRows to present at the end of all the Scenes with a `UITableViewController`.

I have a `variableScene` that I pass around from `Scene` to `Scene`.

I need to assign `numberOfRowsSceneXX` = //an integer

XX will come from `variableScene`, which could be any number from 1 - 10.

So when we get to the last scene, we'll have a value for each Section (`numberOfRowInSection`) which will be represented by each `Scene`: `numberOfRowScene1`, `numberOfRowsScene2`, etc.

I tried to simplify the question.  Hope it makes sense.

Comment: What is the use case for this? You can concatenate tokens with macros `#define SECTION_ROW(name) sectionRow ## name` but I'd be interested to know what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: You almost certainly want an array of `NSInteger`s here. What are you trying to do? This looks like you're trying to solve a problem "the hard way".

Comment: According to your update, it's still not persuading why an array can't be used. You can have a global array (or at least an array where all the Scenes can access to update). For every scene, you update numberOfRowsInScene[i], where i = variableScene-1. Unless it's not what you are up to.

Comment: Use an `NSArray`.  Once compiled, local and (c-)global variables only exist as memory addresses or even just registers; names are only a way to make it easier for you to keep straight what is what. Technically, it is possible to do this with properties, but it's a really bad idea.

Comment: Got it.  Makes sense.  Thanks.  If someone wants to answer it, I'll mark it as an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use arrays.

set it up as:

```
#define MAX_SCENES 10
NSInteger numberOfRows[MAX_SCENES];
```

then when you want to set the value:

```
if (variableScene < MAX_SCENES) {
  numberOfRows[variableScene] = variable;
}
```